# Import text file into SQL Server table using SqlBulkCopy in C# (How to use it?)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm new to coding, I'm trying to import a small text file into a SQL Srever table using `SqlBulkCopy` class, but I failed. It's an exercise, but it's very important for me.

This is the only code I've done. Please some body can  help me to find what next.

```
string CadenaCon = "Data Source=CH-PC;Initial Catalog=Importar;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(CadenaCon);
```

The File path is 'C:\ok\test1.txt'

Comment: If you have your data in a textfile you would be better off using [bcp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) instead. Also you need to narrow your question down to a specific problem. Right now your question is basically "Teach me C# from scratch" and this site is not for those kinds of questions.

Comment: Check this link 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173839(v=sql.80).aspx
You can use bulk insert in sql. Hope this is important information for you. 
happy Coding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C# code you can do something as below:

```
        int i = 0;
        const string connectionString = "Data Source=CH-PC;Initial Catalog=Importar;Integrated Security=True";
        var dbConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\sourcefiles\test.txt");
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        string[] strArray = line.Split(',');
        var dt = new DataTable();

        for (int index = 0; index < strArray.Length; index++)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());

        do
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            string[] itemArray = line.Split(',');
            row.ItemArray = itemArray;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            i = i + 1;
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));


        var bc = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null)
        {
            DestinationTableName = "TestData",
            BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count
        };
        dbConn.Open();
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
        dbConn.Close();
        bc.Close();
```

But as Scott mentioned, you should be having some basic understanding of C# coding to start with.

Comment: If a execption is thrown by `bc.WriteToServer(dt);` how would `dbConn` get closed? You should not teach a new programmer bad habits like not using a `using` statement on his disposable objects. (btw, using a `using` statement would fix that first problem I asked about)

Comment: Thanks to Screedhar, your code worked perfect. I also appreciate  Scott and Tonny's comments. I had already done this exercise using bcp.exe and Bulk in SQL Server's Stored Procedure.  I just needed to explore this option. Thanks to all of you who invested time in helping me to find the solution. And excuse my English, this is not my native language. I'm learning it too.